# How to make a maximize and normal windowstate all in one button

Tags: c#, operating-system, window, maximize-window, windowstate

[I want a simple way to maximize and normal windowstate all in one button (click me for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CtvG.png)

Method (code) c# coding -

```
    int maxornot;

    private void MaxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        maxornot = 1;

        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized);
        {
            maxornot = 0;
        }

        if (maxornot == 0);
        {

        }

    }
```

if this method is pointless and there is a way to simplify the code then leave a code below.

p.s i didn't put much thought into how to get this method to work cause im just having headaches :P

Comment: If there somthing wrong with the question please tell me cause every time i post any form of question it gets down voted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you already showed in your code-example you want a button to Switch from `FormWindowState.Normal` to `FormWindowState.Maximized` and the other way as well.

Now instead of Setting the `FormWindowState` of your form to Maximized at the start of your click Even you should first check the current state of your Window:

```
if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    ... do something
```

[FormWindowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate(v=vs.90).aspx) has 3 different states: `Normal`, `Minimized` and `Maximized`. In your case you don't need `Minimized`. All you have to do now is Switch between normal and maximized in your method depending on what is current active:

```
if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
else
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

This 4 rows of code are all you need in the click event method.

This simple `if-else` may also be converted to a ternary:

```
this.WindowState = this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized ? FormWindowState.Normal : FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I wish there was a way to thank you  better than just leaving a check mark xD
p.s i completely forgot about "else" function lol